# Help me rewrite this sentence

Tags: style

I would like help re-writing this sentence.  I would like the overall tone of the language kept intact, and I would like it to be as concise, eloquent and well written as possible.

> In the event you feel like that this study is not a match for your qualification, ...

I have come up with two versions:

**Version 1**

> In the event you feel that this study is not a match for your qualification, ...

**Version 2**

> In the event you feel this study is not a match for your qualification, ...

Does either of these have an advantage over the other?  Is there another, better way to write it and meet the goals I've given?

Comment: Vote to close as subjective. Pick the sentence you like best, not what Random Person A likes best.

Comment: Agreed, this question is far too open-ended. What does "best" mean? What's the context of this sentence?

Answer (score 4):

> If you don't feel you qualify for this
>   study,

Comment: or "If you feel you don't qualify for this study,"

Answer (score 0):

"If you are unqualified [ or overqualified or underqualified ] for this study ... "

Answer (score 0):

If your qualifications don't match this study,...

If this study does not match your qualifications,...

But wait, how could a study truly match someone's qualifications?